# Exasol SQL Fuzzy Matching function

Tags: sql, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-comparison, looker, exasol

Good day, all you SQL geniuses out there. I'm running into a bit of an issue. The firm I work at uses EXASOL SQL and I'm trying to get find a function that I can use in order to fuzzy match two strings.

For example, Let's say we have these two strings:

*1. 123 ALPHABET STREET*

*2. 123 ALPHABET ST*

I would want to know how similar those two strings are, but the Exasol SQL the firm uses (Metabase / Looker), does not appear to have functions like compged() or something similar. Does anyone out there have any functions that can help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: You mentioned Metabase and Looker. Neither of those is a SQL DBMS; they both can use SQL DBMSs as data sources. Stored functions that compute Levenshtein distance are available for many of those same DBMSs. But you didn't mention which one you use. Plus, Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask for pointers to resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [EDIT_DISTANCE](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/sql_references/functions/alphabeticallistfunctions/edit_distance.htm) to compute the Levenshtein distance in Exasol.

If you need a custom function to compute another distance metric you can define a [User Defined Function (UDF)](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/database_concepts/udf_scripts.htm) in Lua, Python, Java, or R.